# Making code short & form validation

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a simple code which is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    input{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #nameInput{
        width: 250px;
        margin-left: 60px;

    }
    #ageInput{
        width: 70px;
        margin-left: 71px;
    }
    #emailInput{
        width: 250px;
        margin-left: 60px;
    }
    #dateInput{
        margin-left: 9px;
    }
    #myButton{
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
    #yourData{
        margin-top: 100px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #dataDetails, td, th{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #dataDetails{
        width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #warning{
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: red;
    }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

<form>
Name <input type = "text" id="nameInput" required /><br>
Age <input type = "number" id="ageInput" required /><br>
Email <input type = "email" id="emailInput" required /><br>
Joinging Date <input type = "date" id = "dateInput" required />
</form>
<button id="myButton">Submit</button>
<p id="yourData"></p>
<table id="dataDetails"></table>
<p id="warning"></p>

<script>

    var name = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("ageInput").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
    var join = document.getElementById("dateInput").value;
    var tableRow = "";

    function myFunction(){

        tableRow = tableRow + "<tr>";
        tableRow = tableRow + "<th>" + "Your Name" + "</th>";
        tableRow = tableRow + "<th>" + "Your Age" + "</th>";
        tableRow = tableRow + "<th>" + "Your Email" + "</th>";
        tableRow = tableRow + "<th>" + "Your Joining Date" + "</th>";
        tableRow = tableRow + "</tr>";

        tableRow = tableRow + "<tr>";
        tableRow = tableRow + "<td>" + name + "</td>";
        tableRow = tableRow + "<td>" + age + "</td>";
        tableRow = tableRow + "<td>" + email + "</td>";
        tableRow = tableRow + "<td>" + join + "</td>";


    tableRow = tableRow + "</tr>";
    return tableRow;
}

    var click = 0;


    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function(){
        click = click + 1;

        if (click==1) {
        document.getElementById("yourData").innerHTML = "Here is your filled data";
        document.getElementById("dataDetails").innerHTML = myFunction();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Details have already been added";
    }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's working pretty fine but HTML5 validations are not working properly. If I don't fill them, they don't give any warning & same is happening for wrong entered fields except making it red. It will make table without any details. How can I fix it with HTML5.

Also I am wondering if I can make codes some short. I mean for two rows, I have to use tr tag two times. Can I make any loop for it & put different data in them. I tried it but the problem is it's inserting same data two times. Please help!

Comment: I would expect the table to be duplicated each time you click as well

Comment: A side note: form input elements validation should **mandatory** validated/filtered/checked on server side also (in your script) in order to prevent SQL injections or spam emails!

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions. Well mplungjan!, you are right, so I have put a if else statement to prevent duplicating the table.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
<form>
...
</form>
<button id="myButton">Submit</button>
```

your submit button is outside of form,

put your submit button inside form

```
<form>
Name <input type = "text" id="nameInput" required /><br>
Age <input type = "number" id="ageInput" required /><br>
Email <input type = "email" id="emailInput" required /><br>
Joinging Date <input type = "date" id = "dateInput" required />
<button id="myButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y5L90t9/1/)

Comment: Also, you should put javascript variables inside `myFunction()`

Comment: Hi! If I put button inside form tag, then created table will be disappeared at once. Please check once. How to prevent that?

Comment: you can put `return false;` inside onclick to prevent form post